# Strange behavior when running start.bat file in Windows 2019 Core

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd

I have a start.bat which does nothing but

```
@echo off
Echo "Hello World"
```

Then I open a cmd window and type in

```
start "" /D D:\Test start.bat
```

it opens a new cmd window with "Hello World", but **does not close the window automatically**.

Now I created another bat file named start2.bat which has the same content as the start.bat above. Then I type in

```
start "" /D D:\Test start2.bat
```

it opens a new cmd window with "Hello World", and **does close the window automatically**.

Why is it happening ???

I try to use some trace tool to analyse, from the tool, it seems like my system turn `start "" /D D:\Test start.bat` to `cmd.exe /K start.bat`
[TraceTool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f80op.png)

Tried in another computer, now, no matter which file name I used, it turns into `cmd/exe /K start.bat`
[start3.bat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMkjx.png)

---

Update:

Turns out adding /C does not work for me, attach process tree below, the system still changes **/C** to **/K**

[Process tree view with /C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9CcG.png)

---

Update:

Provide full process view. My start.bat is exactly the same as above
And now I open a cmd.exe window, and typed in

`"c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /C START "test" /D "C:\test" start.bat` or just `cmd /C START "test" /D "C:\test" start.bat`

And

`"c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /C START "test" /D "C:\test" start2.bat` or just `cmd /C START "test" /D "C:\test" start2.bat`

From the process tree view, it can be seen that the first command turns into

`C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /K start.bat`

While the second command turns into
`C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "c:\test\start2.bat" "`

cmd.exe

[Full Process Tree View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH2tY.png)

Comment: I don't see a difference between executing `start "" /D D:\Test start.bat` and `start "" /D D:\Test start2.bat` with both batch files containing `@echo Hello World`. In both cases the Windows Command Processor (`cmd.exe`) uses the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) to run `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` with option `/K` and `start.bat` respectively `start2.bat` as arguments. I observed this with [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

Comment: @Mofi Exactly the same error as I got from my machine!! `Not enough storage is available to process this command.` I tried to add the title, the error disappeared!!

Comment: Acutually, I just tried added /C but it stil not work .. /C changes to /K again.. attached process monitor view

Comment: `cmd.exe \k start.bat` is wrong as the option must be specified with `/k` or `/K`, but not with `\k`. The character `/` is for command line options and ``\`` is the directory separator on Windows `\k` is interpreted according to the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) as file/folder `k` in root directory of current drive and not as option `/K` to keep `cmd.exe` running after execution of the batch file which should really have a better and more meaningful name than `start.bat`. What is started?

Comment: What you need is `start "Meaningful title according to what is started" /D "D:\Test" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /K start.bat`. Let's say there is started with the batch file an FTP Client like `%SystemRoot%\System32\ftp.exe`. In this case a good title for the batch file would be `Start_FTP_Client.cmd` and a good command line to us would be `start "FTP Client" /D "D:\Test" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /K Start_FTP_Client.cmd`. `/K` could be repaced by `/C`. `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` (best) could be replaced by `%ComSpec%` (good) or just `cmd.exe` (bad) or just `cmd` (worst).

Comment: The directory containing the batch file must be enclosed in `"` on containing __after__ expansion of all environment variable references a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~``. You have the folder path not readable for us. Do you know the predefined [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) as output in a command prompt window on running just `set` with their values like `USERPROFILE`?

Comment: The data displayed in the process tree view could be posted in question also as text. It shows us that you are not really running the `start` command line from within a command prompt window opened by you. There is executed `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C START "test" /D %SystemRoot%\obfuscated path start.bat`. So what you wrote about which command line was executed by you and what is shown in the monitoring tool do not match at all. We are wasting our time (yours and ours) on looking on your [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please [edit] your question and describe the entire task.

Comment: Hi @Mofi, I am still working directly from cmd.exe, but typed in `"c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /C START "test" /D "C:\test" start.bat` this time. The start.bat does nothing but echo a "Hello World". As I can seen from the process tree, this commands turns into `C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /K start.bat`. Whearas, if  I typed in `"c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /C START "test" /D "C:\test" start2.bat`, the command truns into `C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "c:\test\start2.bat" "`as expected.

Comment: I did not find a good way to paste the process tree view in text...Sorry for that, I have attached a screenshot instead..but the behavior is the same as I described..Changing the start.bat name to other names worked perfectly, but I am confused why the name 'start.bat' does not work..

Comment: You make your tests wrong. A Windows command prompt window is an already running `cmd.exe`. If you run now a command line which starts with `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe`, the entire command line is finally interpreted by __two__ `cmd.exe` which in some cases depending on the arguments requires a different syntax than using running from another processes like `explorer.exe` (shortcut file) or Windows task scheduler (scheduled task) or any other executable than `cmd.exe` the same command line.

Comment: So if you want to test such command lines, test it with a shortcut file with property __Target__ being the command line finally used by the executable which really starts the Windows command processor with option `/C` to process a batch file and finally close itself. Please look on what I posted as command line and what you executed as command line. The program to run by `start` is `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` with __CMD__ option `/C` and the batch file as one more argument with the directory specified after __START__ option `/D` with the path of the current working directory for `cmd.exe`.

Comment: In a command prompt window the command line would be (best) `start "Program Name" /D "C:\test" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C "StartProgramName.cmd"`. The same command line as __Target__ in a shortcut file for testing would be `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C start "Program Name" /D "C:\test" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C "StartProgramName.cmd"`. Run in the command prompt window `cmd /?` and read the output usage help for an explanation of __CMD__ option `/D` which must be left to __CMD__ option `/C` on making use of it.

Answer (score 2):

From the usage information of the [`start` command](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) (excerpt from the description of the `command/program` argument):

> ```cmd
> [...]
>     command/program
>                 If it is an internal cmd command or a batch file then
>                 the command processor is run with the /K switch to cmd.exe.
>                 This means that the window will remain after the command
>                 has been run.
>
>                 If it is not an internal cmd command or batch file then
>                 it is a program and will run as either a windowed application
>                 or a console application.
> [...]
> ```

Hence when starting an internal command or a batch file, [`cmd.exe`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) together with its `/K` option is used, so `start "" "script.bat"` is equivalent to:

```cmd
start "" cmd.exe /K "script.bat"
```

If you want the new console window to become closed, use this instead:

```cmd
start "" cmd.exe /C "script.bat"
```

Comment: I have followed your advice and added /C, it still does not work for me, the system changes it to /K eventually..

Comment: Do not call the script `start.bat`, use a different name to avoid unintended cyclic calls when you intend to run the internal command `start`…